# I want countdown timer to redirect to url after timer hits 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I have a working countdown timer but want it to redirect to an url or show a popup with a message to continue to another url when the counter hits zero.  any advice is appreciated.

countdown.js

```js
function calcage(secs, num1, num2) {
  s = ((Math.floor(secs/num1))%num2).toString();
  if (LeadingZero && s.length < 2)
    s = "0" + s;
  return "<b>" + s + "</b>";
}

function CountBack(secs) {
  if (secs < 0) {
    document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
    return;
  }
  DisplayStr = DisplayFormat.replace(/%%D%%/g, calcage(secs,86400,100000));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%H%%/g, calcage(secs,3600,24));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%M%%/g, calcage(secs,60,60));
  DisplayStr = DisplayStr.replace(/%%S%%/g, calcage(secs,1,60));

  document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = DisplayStr;
  if (CountActive)
    setTimeout("CountBack(" + (secs+CountStepper) + ")", SetTimeOutPeriod);
}

function putspan(backcolor, forecolor) {
 document.write("<span id='cntdwn'></span>");
}

if (typeof(BackColor)=="undefined")
  BackColor = "white";
if (typeof(ForeColor)=="undefined")
  ForeColor= "black";
if (typeof(TargetDate)=="undefined")
  TargetDate = 17;/* number of hours            "12/31/2020 5:00 AM";*/
if (typeof(DisplayFormat)=="undefined")
  DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
if (typeof(CountActive)=="undefined")
  CountActive = true;
if (typeof(FinishMessage)=="undefined")
  FinishMessage = "";
if (typeof(CountStepper)!="number")
  CountStepper = -1;
if (typeof(LeadingZero)=="undefined")
  LeadingZero = true;


CountStepper = Math.ceil(CountStepper);
if (CountStepper == 0)
  CountActive = false;
var SetTimeOutPeriod = (Math.abs(CountStepper)-1)*1000 + 990;
putspan(BackColor, ForeColor);
//var dthen = new Date(TargetDate);
//var dnow = new Date();
//if(CountStepper>0)
//  ddiff = new Date(dnow-dthen);
//else
  ddiff = new Date(TargetDate * 300000);
gsecs = Math.floor(ddiff.valueOf()/1000);
CountBack(gsecs);
```

html

```html
<!-- COUNTDOWN TIMER -->
<div style="text-align:center">
<div class="content">

<div class="box">
  <div id="top">
   <h2 style="line-height: 20px">You have <span style="color:red; font-size:20px">
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = 1;
//BackColor = "palegreen";
//ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%H%%:%%M%%:%%S%%";
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="js/countdown.js"></script></span> to claim your FREE spins.</h2>
  

        </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The popup should be simple with just a statement and an option to continue.

Comment: Do you know how to redirect a page without a timer?

Answer (score 2):

You already check wether the countdown is complete here:

```
if (secs < 0) {
  document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
  return;
}
```

So you could simply add the changes into there, or call out to a "countdownComplete" type function. e.g.

```
if (secs < 0) {
  document.getElementById("cntdwn").innerHTML = FinishMessage;
  countdownComplete();
  return;
}
```

With a `countdownComplete` function available somewhere relevant in the script, containing something like:

```
function countdownComplete(){
  document.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
}
```

Comment: Thanks DBS.  Used your advice and all is working well now.